# How do I enable the jetpack mutator in Red Eclipse?

Tags: linux, red-eclipse

I installed [Red Eclipse](https://redeclipse.net/), v1.5.8-1 from the Debian repositories, but I can't figure out how to enable the jetpack mutator. I remember it being there in a version on an earlier release of Debian, but I don't remember exactly which one. Was it removed? It's not listed in [the guide](https://redeclipse.net/wiki/Guide) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play testing showed that the "jetpack" mutator wasn't really fun in the overall scheme of things and felt more like a random thing than something you'd use all the time.

We replaced the mutator with "freestyle", which allows you to use all your abilities without the normal limitations like requiring energy to perform the moves. This felt like a more natural and fun way to experience the abilities in Red Eclipse while still maintaining coherent gameplay.

The basic mechanics of the jet pack are actually still hidden inside the code and activates if you set the variable "gravity" to zero.

I hope this helps. If you need further help I recommend our forums and/or chat room as this question is really a topic for the people who make the game (us!). You've been fortunate enough to trigger a email alert this time ;)

Sincerely,
Quinton Reeves,
Lead Developer, Red Eclipse

Comment: Always fun to see devs themselves answering questions on our site :)